# how do you set WinInet to use a bearer token

Tags: oauth-2.0, wininet

I am using OAuth2 with a server, and wininet as the http client. I cannot see how to set wininet to use a bearer token (just see how to set username and password for basic authentication). Is it possible to tell wininet to use a bearer token? (something like INTERNET_OPTION_USERNAME...)

Comment: There is no username/password in OAuth. You first have to get a token. For a desktop application this is usually done by asking the user to login through the browser, the browser will put the token in windows title, then use that token to send request with WinINet

Comment: "then use that token to send request with WinINet" - yes, that's the question - how?

Comment: Show what you have done already. I don't even know what language you use. I think you have client secret + authorization token, now you want to get bearer token by posting request through `HttpSendRequest`

Comment: I have the bearer token no problems. I want to tell WinInet to use it in the Authorization header.

Answer (score 0):

This is same code to get access token from google. Note `InternetOpenA` uses `NULL` for username and password. If successful it reads a JSON file in to `str`  which will contain access token, this access token is used with subsequent GET/POST requests.

```
std::string client_secret = "123";
std::string client_id = "1234";
std::string authorization_token = "token from browser";

std::string query, header;

{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "code=" << authorization_token
        << "&client_id=" << client_id << ".apps.googleusercontent.com"
        << "&client_secret=" << client_secret
        << "&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code";
    query = ss.str();
}

{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-length: "
        << query.size() << "\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    header = ss.str();
}

HINTERNET hopen = InternetOpenA("appname", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
HINTERNET hconnect = InternetConnectA(hopen,
    "accounts.google.com", INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT,
    NULL, //username
    NULL, //password
    INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);

HINTERNET hrequest = HttpOpenRequestA(hconnect, "POST", "o/oauth2/token", 
    NULL, "http://localhost", 
    NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE | INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE, 0);
if(hrequest)
{
    BOOL res = HttpSendRequestA(hrequest, header.c_str(), header.size(), 
        &query[0], query.size());

    std::string data;
    if(res)
    {
        DWORD received;
        const int bufsize = 4096;
        std::vector<BYTE> buf(bufsize);
        while(InternetReadFile(hrequest, &buf[0], bufsize, &received) && received)
            data.insert(data.end(), buf.begin(), buf.begin() + received);
        std::string str(data.begin(), data.end());
        //=> access token
    }
    InternetCloseHandle(hrequest);
}
InternetCloseHandle(hconnect);
InternetCloseHandle(hopen);
```

Comment: So that's the code to get to the bearer token, yes. But having got it, how do I tell WinInet to use it in subsequent requests? In other words, what happens next after this set of code?

Answer (score 0):

Pass "Authorization: Bearer " + the token to HttpAddRequestHeaders(). In my case I had to  access an IdentityServer API from a win32 C++ MFC (WinInet) Client. Make sure to set InternetConnect() with the server domain instead of an IP address and that the token has correct scopes.

```
HINTERNET hSession, hConnect, hRequest;
hSession = InternetOpen( NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0 );
if( hSession )
{
    CString strServerDomain = GetServerDomainName();
    hConnect = InternetConnect( hSession, strServerDomain, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, 
    NULL, NULL,INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0 );
    if( hConnect )
    {
        hRequest = HttpOpenRequest( hConnect, "GET", strParams, NULL, NULL, 0, 
        INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE | INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE, 0 );   // strParams = "projectName/controller/Action/"
        if( hRequest )
        {
            CString strToken = "Your Token Goes Here";  // Token
            CString strHeader = "";
            strHeader.Format( "Authorization: Bearer %s", strToken );

            BOOL bHeaderAdded = HttpAddRequestHeaders( hRequest, strHeader, strHeader.GetLength(), 0 );
            ASSERT( bHeaderAdded );

            BOOL hHttpRequest = HttpSendRequest( hRequest, NULL, 0, NULL, 0 );
```